# PHP Handling complex requests through single entry point app

Tags: php

I have been developing a Sports Management website with user, roster, and schedule management using PHP and JS. This app has about 15 database tables to work with altogether. Recently I learned I was doing something majorly wrong: I was using individual PHP scripts as their own "apps".

Example: Individual scripts app

**JS**

```
var params = {
   action : 'addGame',
   date : 'someday',
   hometeam : 1,
   awayteam : 2
}
$.post('/php/scheduler.php', params);
```

**PHP**

```
class Scheduler extends TableManager{

    public function addGame($date, $hometeam, $awayteam){
       // do sql stuff
    }

    public function doAction($request){
        switch($request){
            case "addGame":
                 return $this->addGame($_REQUEST['date'], $_REQUEST['hometeam'], $_REQUEST['awayteam'];
                 break;
        }
    }

    }

if(isset($_REQUEST['action'])){
   $scheduler = new Scheduler();
   $scheduler->doAction($_REQUEST['action']);
}
```

I learned that writing a proper PHP  application means there should be a single "app" where all requests are routed. This is fine and I've done this - but now I face unknown territory. If I have 15 tables, and they all have a few very specific functions (they all `extend TableManager` to provide basic table functions, but some are obviously more specific) how can I write a request processor in my main `App` that handles requests for every table, without getting insanely complex?

Example: Single entry point app

**JS**

```
var params = {
   action : 'addGame',
   table : 'scheduler',
   date : 'someday',
   hometeam : 1,
   awayteam : 2
}
$.post('/php/app.php', params);
```

**PHP**

```
class App {

   private $scheduleTable;

   public function createTable($name){
        switch($name){
            case "scheduler":
               $this->scheduleTable = new Scheduler();
               break;
        } 
   }

   public doAction($request){
     switch($request){
            case "addGame":
                 $this->createTable('scheduler');
                 return $this->scheduleTable->addGame($_REQUEST['date'], $_REQUEST['hometeam'], $_REQUEST['awayteam'];
                 break;
        }
   }

}

if(isset($_REQUEST['action'])){
   $app = new App();
   $app ->doAction($_REQUEST['action']);
}
```

Now I need to start using complex and bloated switch statements, as my tables all inherit `TableManager` and thus do many of the same actions, but also have unique functions. I'll need to `switch` on the incoming `action`, and then `switch` on the `table`. Not to mention all of the other features that this `App` will have (user system, for one). Is the only answer to write a massive switch statement?

Comment: [Routing](https://packagist.org/search/?q=router).

Comment: You should take a look at php frameworks such as Symfony or Laravel that take care of low level details for you (such as routing, for instance..)

Comment: I went and wrote my own router. For a small app like mine it only took a few hours.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand of your current predicament, yes. You could always use a PHP framework (Google them, there are many) but if you want to use your existing structure then of course you need a switch statement or a way to load the correct models for the page.

Note that you could always use something like this:

```
<?php

    // I assume $request is sanitized.
    // Check to see if the class file exists.
    if( file_exists( 'class-directory/' . $request . '.inc.php' ) ) {
        $class_name = ucfirst( $request );
        $this->scheduleTable = new $class_name;
    } else {
        // Show error page, the request is not valid.
    }

?>
```

**Important note**: for more security you should use $_POST, $_GET and $_COOKIE instead of $_REQUEST.

Comment: If all my `$_REQUEST` values are bound into statements using PDO, what's the difference?

Comment: It's simply to prevent overriding values depending on the order in which `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE` get processed into `$_REQUEST`. Note that you can still use my solution even if you keep using `$_REQUEST`.